# I want to filter 24000 data and delete noisy data

Tags: matlab, filtering

I have 24000 data (from ADV that sent 200 Hz frequency in 120 seconds) and I want to filter them and delete noisy data.
I used fdatool in Matlab and change frequency specification but the results are not that I have expected(I didn't know what frequency should be selected then I start from 5 to 90 for Fpass and 10 to 100 for Fstop).
( After that I used medfilt1 and I change nth-order one-dimensional median filter from 10 to 1000. but the results are not that I expected.
I have any information about filtering technique. please advise me for filter my data.

Comment: First of all which results you expect? Why what you get doesn't satisfy you? Do you know which kind of noise you have?

Comment: Would you please publish your code to have better chance to receive answer ? Thanks !

Comment: I get data from ADV instrument and the software of ADV can filter of data. But I want to filter data with other way and compare this filtering method by the filtering of ADV software. when I plot the filtering data, yet noisy data in filtering data have seen.

Comment: b=xlsread('all data.xlsx');
vx1=filter(b50,1,Vx1);%b50 is defined to filter data fpass 50 and fstop 80 
vz1=filter(b50,1,Vz1);
covxz1=cov(vx1,vz1,'omitrows');
vxmean1=mean(vx1,'omitnan');
vzmean1=mean(vz1,'omitnan');